# Prove the independence of $A \cup B$ and $A$ given that $A$ and $B$ in $]0, 1[$

Tags: probability-theory, set-theory, independence

Suppose A and B are events with $0 < P(A) < 1$ and $0 < P(B) < 1$. If A and B are independent, can $A \cup B$ and A be independent? How to use the prove by contradiction in this case?

Comment: WDYM by "independent"

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please clearly state what you want to know and show what you have done or share what are your thoughts. Don'r directly ask for an answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

A slight correction to the answer of @RalphClausen.  From
$$\begin{align}0&=P(A)\bigl(1-P(A\cup B)\bigr)\\
&=P(A)\bigl(1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B)\bigr)\\
&=P(A)\bigl(1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A)P( B)\bigr)\\
&=P(A)\bigl(1-P(A)\bigr)\bigl(1-P(B)\bigr)\\
\end{align}$$
we conlude $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$ or $P(B)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$.

Suppose $A\cup B$ and $A$ are independent. Thus $P((A \cup B)\cap A) = P(A)P(A\cup B)$. Also, since $(A\cup B) \cap A = A$, $P((A \cup B)\cap A) = P(A)$.

This implies $$P(A) = P(A \cup B) P(A) \implies P(A)(1-P(A \cup B)) = 0$$

This implies either $P(A) = 0 \implies A = \emptyset$ or $P(A \cup B) = 1$ which means $B$ is the total sample space.

Rest is easy.

Comment: +1, except for your last statement: $P(M)=1$ doesn't mean that $M$ is the total sample space. And $P(B) =0$ doesn't mean that $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes. @MichaelHoppe you're correct.